# the value does not change when the state is changed

Tags: reactjs

when the search value is changed, the state does not change, although when the search value is reduced, the changes occur instantly

this is one code in order*

```
       if(prop.props.statePokemon){

        prop.props.setStatePokemon(false)
```

why the given value does not change:

```
setPokemon(saveDataPokemon) // the value does not change
```

but all other logs are going fine:

```
        let rangePokemonFromAttack:(IPokemon | undefined | any)[] = allPokemon.data.map((pokemon: IPokemon) => {
            if(prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackFrom <= pokemon.stats[1].base_stat && pokemon.stats[1].base_stat <= prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackTo){
                return  pokemon
            }  
            }).filter((pokemon: IPokemon | undefined) => {
                return pokemon !== undefined
            })

        console.log(allPokemon,'all',
                    saveDataPokemon, 'save',
                    rangePokemonFromAttack ,'range')

        if(typeof rangePokemonFromAttack[0] !== 'undefined'){
            setPokemon(saveDataPokemon)
            setPokemon({data: rangePokemonFromAttack})
        }else{
            setPokemon(saveDataPokemon)
        }
    }
    prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackFrom = 0
    prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackTo = 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The state variables doesn't change like that you need to use **setState()** function for this purpose, which in turn calls the render again. For more info Google setState or visit this link ***https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html*** In this docs search setState function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake and caused another state

```
prop.props.setStatePokemon(false)
let rangePokemonFromAttack:IPokemon[] = saveDataPokemon.data.filter((pokemon: IPokemon) => {
        if(prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackFrom <= pokemon.stats[1].base_stat 
            && pokemon.stats[1].base_stat 
            <= prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackTo){
            return  pokemon
        }  
    })
if(typeof rangePokemonFromAttack[0] !== 'undefined'){
    setPokemon({data: rangePokemonFromAttack})
}else{
    setPokemon(saveDataPokemon)
}
```

Comment: Glad to see that you removed the `.map`, but you can clean up the `.filter` even more! You don't need to `return pokemon`.  You already have the correct filter condition in there.  `saveDataPokemon.data.filter((pokemon: IPokemon) => prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackFrom <= pokemon.stats[1].base_stat && pokemon.stats[1].base_stat <= prop.props.rangeAttack.rangeAttackTo )`.  The `.filter` will keep all pokemon for which that condition is `true` and remove the ones where it is `false`.